# Android setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) not working at all after screen rotation in KITKAT

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

> Please note that same code is working perfectly fine on Android
>   Versions > KitKat

I have a dynamic view of questionnaire. All views are being added according to question coming up from the api I am using. What I am trying to do is, If question was required but user didn't filled it and trying to submit it, I am trying to setVisibility as 'VISIBLE' to my TextView having text "Required"

It works perfectly fine when I am either in Landscape or in Portrait mode, but right after changing the orientation, it stops working.

I have debugged the code and checked, status of visibility is being changed but UI is not being updated.

> It is working fine other than KITKAT

I have tried view.invalidate(); as well.

TextView layout to be set as VISIBLE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/required_prompt_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.goodsnitch.lib.ui.LatoRegularTextView
        android:id="@+id/required_prompt_dynamic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/field_required_prompt"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Java Code to make it visible

```
private void showRequiredPrompt(final View view) {
        final TextView requiredLabel = (TextView) ((LinearLayout) view.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.required_prompt_dynamic);
        if (requiredLabel != null) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    view.clearAnimation();
                    requiredLabel.clearAnimation();
                    requiredLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    view.invalidate();
                    requiredLabel.invalidate();
                }
            }, 200);
        }
    }
```

I will appreciate your help :)

Editing question to explain further

[This is code to show the label ON CLICK EVENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA1qQ.jpg)
[This is the toast showing visibility state of the label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZv4H.png)

Required label should appear just above first checkbox in RED color

Comment: You have to save state. Take a look at: [Saving Android Activity state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-android-activity-state)

Comment: @Alexandar G: Its not about state, I am not trying to restore the state, I am trying to simply show the View on submit button click (if needed)

Comment: "but right after changing the orientation, it stops working" As Alexandar mentioned, you have to save current state of the view. Whenever there is change in rotation, activity is re-created. Try to add android:configChanges="orientation" in AndroidManifest.xml for that activity

Comment: @YasirTahir, I meant after orientation changed, ON MY BUTTON CLICK EVENT, my layout is not being refreshed

Comment: @YasirTahir:
Let me explain:
Success Scenario
1. I came on the screen
2. Left field empty
3. Click on submit button
4. Required Label shows up. (Correct)

Fail Scenario
1. I came on the screen
2. Rotated the screen
3. Left field empty
4. Click on submit button
5. Required label should show up. (It doesn't - Failure)

It has nothing to do with saveState.. It is button click even which shows or hide the label

Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

use onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() when u are using screen rotation.